# JTable search not giving the searched row selected row data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablerowsorter

I am trying to get the searched row data from `JTable` into `JTextField` components but when I'm searching it is not giving the searched row selected row data.

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    DefaultTableModel obj = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    jTextField1.setText(obj.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
    jTextField2.setText(obj.getValueAt(row, 2).toString());
}           

private void filter(String query) {
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table);
    jTable1.setRowSorter(tr);
    tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> pr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(table3);
    jTable3.setRowSorter(pr);
    pr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));
}
```

Comment: Please 1) add more text to the question itself, explaining the code and the problem in greater detail. 2) Format the code better (adding more text to the question will allow you to do this. 3) Also, you'll want to go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Note also that it would be best if you could create and post a small self-contained program that illustrates your problem, and post it in your question as code-formatted text, a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Your JTable is filtered so you can't get the data directly from the model using the table row index because not all the model data is displayed in the table so you may not have a one-to-one mapping.

Instead you need to convert the row of the table to the actual row in the TableModel:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
int modelRow = jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
jTextField1.setText(model.getValueAt(modelRow, 1).toString());
jTextField2.setText(model.getValueAt(modelRow, 2).toString());
```